# Error -- > exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown.; when I convert an ISO image to tarball and docker import it

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to create a container from the ISO image, trying following commands on ubuntu.

1. ```
   curl -SLO https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/35/Workstation/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-35-1.2.iso
   ```
2. ```
   sudo guestfish --ro -a Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-35-1.2.iso -m /dev/sda1 tar-out / fedora-35.tar
   ```
3. ```
   cat fedora-35.tar | docker import - fedora35:v1
   ```
4. ```
   docker run 016ffc836ada /bin/sh
   docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
   ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
   ```
5. For some reason the image inspect gives the json metadata null

   ```
    "Container": "",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "DockerVersion": "20.10.7",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
   ```

I have seen other similar posts but those did not help. Not sure how to fix it. Could you please advise?
Thanks,

Comment: I edited your question to be formatted as Markdown so it renders in a reasonable way. Please do this yourself in the future when asking.

Comment: BTW, have you tried listing the contents of the `tar` file that guestfish extracts? _Is_ there a `/bin/sh`? If not, what files _are_ actually there?

Comment: ...one possibility is that you're extracting the EFI partition, but not the initramfs within it where the actual Linux filesystem is (or a separate partition on the ISO that likewise contains the actual files you want). Listing the files in the tar would make this obvious, and would be much more useful than the huge Docker metadata dump.

Comment: Starting from the [Docker Hub `fedora` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/fedora) will probably be much easier than recreating it from scratch.  You could try adding a [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/) binary to your image so you'll have something to run to debug, but you need to know what you're looking for in terms of, say, where `libc.so` should be.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 'Twas it. Converting *.iso to *gz was only rips/zips EFI System Partition [ESP]. It did not expand on the `./LiveOS/squashfs.img`; which contains the root file system. I ran `nsquashfs /tmp/tmp.kIdsNx24Jk/LiveOS/squashfs.img`, then mounted,  copied and tar the dirs/files.  Post that `cat fedora-squashfs-35.gz | docker import - fedora-squashfs-35:v1` gave the container ID. Then `docker run -it <cont_id> /bin/bash` bring the shell prompt. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidMaze: Thank you for an additional handle on investigation. It helped.

Comment: Still my `docker inspect <image id>` does not return meaningful values except null. Any ideas there?